# Help to kick out the anomaly in proving $Q$ = $K_\text{eq}$

Tags: physical-chemistry

Consider a hypothetical bidirectional reaction ,  $\ce{aA + bB <=> cC + dD}$

(A , B are reactant(s) and C , D are reaction product(s)) ,

As we know the following expressions $Q=\frac{P_C^c.P_D^d}{P_A^a.P_B^b}$ (Q=Reaction Quotient , $P_x$ = Partial Pressure od $x_\text{th}$ reactant/reaction product) and while the reaction is in equilibrium , $K_\text{eq}=\frac{[C]^c.[D]^d}{[A]^a.[B]^b}$ ($K_\text{eq}$= Equilibrium constant of the reaction , [ ] = Concentration for Ideal Solution or Activity for Non-Ideal Solution) please help me to understand why at chemical equilibrium $Q=K_\text{eq}$ holds ,

although $Q$ and $K_\text{eq}$ both are dimensionless quantity , "The expression of $Q$ contains **Partial Pressure** and The expression of $K_\text{eq}$ contains **Concentration for Ideal Solution or Activity for Non-Ideal Solution**"

Comment: "As we know" is an assumption. What's the source of your equations? Is that from a book or from lecture notes? See here: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Equilibria/Chemical_Equilibria/The_Reaction_Quotient There Q is in terms of activities.

Comment: @BuckThorn , There is no mention of Partial Pressure

Comment: The partial pressure and the activity can be related as follows: $a_i=\gamma _i p_i/p^\circ$

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare $K$ and $Q$, you have to define them in terms of the same measures of concentration and the same standard state. The only difference in the definition should be that in order to determine $K$, you are required to use the concentrations or activities of an equilibrium state, while $Q$ may be determined for states that are not necessarily at equilibrium.

> please help me to understand why at chemical equilibrium $Q=K_{eq}$ holds

Once you have the definitions match, it becomes fairly trivial. The equilibrium constant is what you observe whenever the reaction has had enough time to go to equilibrium. The individual equilibrium concentrations might be distinct for different starting concentrations, but $K$ comes out the same (if it does not, it means the reaction is not reaching equilibrium). If $Q$ is not equal to $K$, you are not at equilibrium.

I realize this is a bit of a tautology. The explanation why the particular form of the equilibrium expression leads to a value that is a constant requires a knowledge of how chemical potentials (or $\Delta_r G$) vary with concentration. The reaction will proceed in the direction that minimizes $G$, so at equilibrium $\Delta_r G = \frac{dG}{d \xi}$ will be zero.

Comment: Please give more direct explanation . Actually , this is part of the  proof of Gibbs Free Energy Equation , for ${\Delta_\text{r} G}^o=-RT\ln Q$ is it easy to prove but ${\Delta_\text{r} G}^o=-RT\ln K_\text{eq}$ is a bit hard to establish directly .

Comment: @NilabjaSaha $\Delta_r G^\circ=-RT\ln Q$ doesn't exist... The general equation is 
$\Delta_r G=-RT\ln \Big(\frac{K}{Q}\Big)$ and $\Delta_r G^\circ=-RT\ln K$ is just the special case where you plug in $Q^\circ:=1$.

Comment: @Kexanone I will not update my answer to include this but I encourage you to expand your comment into a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've outlined the derivation of the equation, a more detailed explanation can be found in many phys. chem. and thermodynamics textbooks. Suppose, for simplicity, that the equilibrium is A(g)=B(g) and at constant temperature and pressure. The Gibbs free energy change for the reaction is $dG=(\mu_B-\mu_A)d\xi$ where $\xi$ is the extent of reaction which is $0$ for all reactants and $1$ when one mole of reactants has become product. The chemical potentials are $\mu$. At equilibrium the condition is that the change in free energy $G$ is at a minimum, $(\partial G/\partial \xi)_{T,p} = 0$.  The chemical potentials in terms of the numerical value of the partial pressure $p$ is $\mu=\mu^0+RT\ln(p)$ for each species. Therefore

$$\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial \xi} \right)_{T,p}=\mu_B-\mu_A=\Delta G^\text{o}+RT\ln\left(\frac{p_B}{p_A}\right)$$

and this is equal to the free energy change one mole of A at partial pressure $p_A$ going into B at constant partial pressures. The term $\Delta G^\text{o}=\mu_B^0-\mu_A^0$.

It is convention to label the slope of free energy vs extent of reaction $\displaystyle \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial \xi} \right)_{T,p}\to\Delta G'$ or something similar. The general expression is now

$$\Delta G'=\Delta G^\text{o}+RT\ln\left(\frac{p_B}{p_A}\right)$$

At equilibrium $\Delta G'=0$ and so $\displaystyle \Delta G^\text{o}=-RT\ln\left(\frac{p^e_B}{p^e_A}\right)$ where the superscript $e$ indicates the equilibrium value. Normally we write this as

$$\displaystyle \Delta G^\text{o}=-RT\ln\left(K_p\right)$$

Comment: Regarding $\mu=\mu^\circ+RT\ln(p)$. I know Atkin's and co. do this a lot, but $p$ in this case is **not** the partial pressure here, but a _relative_ partial pressure (relative to the standard state). The equation in terms of partial pressure $p$ is $\mu=\mu^\circ+RT\ln\Big(\frac{p}{p^\circ}\Big)$.

Comment: According to wikipedia, the greek letter commonly used for extent of reaction is Xi, not Zeta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extent_of_reaction

Comment: So does IUPAC: https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/E02283

Comment: Ok I use $p$ as numerical value (as stated in the text) so is dimensionless, $p/p^0$ is also ok. but as  $p^0=1$ its the same. I will change $\zeta$ to $\xi$ but actually any unique symbol will do.

Comment: @porphyrin No, it's not the same. $p^\circ=10^5 Pa$. The only reason it doesn't matter at the end in your case is that the total number of particles doesn't change in your process.

Comment: @Kexanone No: If you use  Pa or  Torr  etc  as we take the ratio vs standard state 1 bar or 1 atm or $10^5$ Pa or 760 torr, whatever we choose, the values cancel out. i.e. 0.5 atm /1 atm, $50000$ Pa /$10^5$ Pa, will be 0.5 what ever the units.